# Software engineer position trial day - "Do"s and "Don't"s

Tags: interviewing, job-search, software-development

After a series of interviews by Skype and even a test task, one IT-company from the EU invited me to a trial day (and I live far from this EU country and I'm even not in the EU)

I've got no idea what a "trial day" there means, I assume it would be like just simulation of typical day at the work.

But the thing is, even though I've googled some stuff I haven't found some answers.

- Should I bring a notepad & pen with me?
- Do I need to take a laptop? (I don't actually have one; mine is broken).
- Is it okay if I bring some sweets/candys (which are produced in my home country) to the coffee room or would it look weird?
- Should I dress casually or formally?

Any other things?

Comment: Are they paying for your travel expenses? To be clear; is this definitely part of an interview and not a "trial period" at the start of the job?

Comment: Can't you simply ask them if you have to bring anything? Only someone in the IT company can answer all your questions.

Comment: @RJFalconer yes, they pay for travelling. It's part of interview

Comment: Voting to close as company-specific. The only people who can tell you what you should bring and what is expected of you are the company you are applying to.

Comment: A notepad and pen is always a good thing to have with you for this kind of thing. Don't even ask about it, just bring it.

Comment: @MarkMark, in your other interviews you hopefully learned some of the technologies you'd be working with and how the company functions.  Now would be a good time to take to studying various technologies so you have a working knowledge enough to maintain a conversation about them.

Comment: The only necessary things are the things they told you to bring. The appropriateness of bringing sweets seems company specific and can thus presumably be risky with no knowledge of company culture. Dress to fit in, don't overdress. Pen and paper can't hurt (at least as long as you keep yourself away from the pointy bits).

Comment: @Kozaky If the OP had just asked the company instead of asking here, we Workplace.SE readers won't benefit from the resulting knowledge about how trial days and related company culture tend to be.

Comment: Weird. Live in brazil, first time I've heard of this. A quick search around our laws here even find something close to that *illegal*.

Comment: @Pere I think Kozaky's point is that there's no way we can know the answer of what the OP should or shouldn't bring, since we don't work at the company. While trial days aren't unheard of, they certainly aren't standard either. What is expected from a trial day is going to vary greatly between companies.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, and that point is an interesting answer by itself, not a reason to put the question in hold.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> What is a trial day?

A "*trial day*" probably means exactly what it says.  They are bring you in to work with them for a day to make sure you know what your doing skills wise, and are a good fit culturally.

> Should I bring notepad & pen with me?

Yes, you should.  This will give you the appearance of being more prepared.  Use it as well to keep all the new information straight in your mind and avoid having your host repeat themselves.

> Do I need to take a laptop?

No, you don't *need* to. I would assume if you're going to work for them you will be provided a computer.  If yours was working I would not see the issue in bringing it though.

> Is it okay if I bring some sweets/candys (which are produced in my home
>   country) to the coffee room or would it look weird?

I think this is a great idea as an ice-breaker / conversation starter.  Don't bring a ton, but bring enough to share.

> Should I dress casually or formally?

If you were not given instructions, **dress formally**.  If you are way over dressed *you can always remove the tie and jacket*.

Comment: Why not "if you were not given instructions, __ask__" ?

Comment: @Erik Why not what?  Ask?  Well of course the OP could have asked, but I think the opportunity might have passed by and that is not much of an answer...

Comment: Great answer! One addition: I found that smart casual works for _most_ software companies here in Europe if you don't own a formal suit.

Comment: Dressing formally depends on the industry. If in some interviews or places  worked II used a suit I would have looked way out of place.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That is when you remove the tie and jacket.  Better to be over than under dressed in my experience.

Comment: @MisterPositive Better to ask, or have the eyes open in the interview phase, that is way they exist...I have worked with people using sandals, and was even interviewed by someone wearing pyjamas. For the banking industry you usually use suit, on most other areas usually in this kind of industry the best is casual. High end street clothes will do the trick usually, dress smart and avoid jeans while unsure. But above all, ask them, not a random bunch of strangers.

Comment: OP talked about an IT company, not the financial industry. A plain shirt is just fine (and technically speaking it is considered the "formal" dress in IT).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto It depends strongly on the country and the specific company.  I think it is a mistake not to ask (but I would ask HR rather than the guy you will be reporting to.)

Comment: @MartinBonner it depends if we are talking about the whole world, sure. But OP clearly mentioned the EU so a good rule of thumb can be "shirt unless you see everyone else is wearing a hoodie".

Comment: Wearing a suit, as a Software Engineer in Europe would generally be taken as a sign that you do _not_ understand company culture. Given the market for Software Engineers, that won't kill your chances, but you'll forever be known as the guy who wore a suit . (I have worked for a consultancy company well-known for wearing suits. We talked for years about the new guy who came in with blue hair. It works both ways. )

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto The EU is a big place.  My experience is that southern Germany is *much* more formal than Berlin or Cambridge.

Comment: @MartinBonner I have dealt with German people, and indeed it is frequent seeing them suited up. However, I have dealt mostly with consultants. Also a rather frequent bad choice for ties, odd.

Comment: @MartinBonner - I would rather be the guy known for wearing a suit and tie then the came in a t-shirt and shorts for a job interview.  You dress for success.

Comment: @Ramhound I have always worn a suit for job interviews.  But wearing the wrong clothes is a *faux pas*.  What is so difficult about "just ask what the office dress code is"?

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer of "Mr. Positive" covers much of the other angles.

As for dressing, have you noticed how your interviewers dressed? That should be a pretty good clue of the company culture for starters. However, better be safe than sorry, ask them.

I have been interviewed by technicians often, over skype and in person, and the way they dress is a pretty good clue; I have people interviewing me usually with casual wear, a couple with jeans and sandals, some with t-shirts.

As a general rule, and considering than the UK is still part of the EC:

In the UK, there are exceptions in more relaxed companies, however using white shirt, and a black, or at most a dark grey suit is still a thing. Better ask.

In pretty much of Europe, if the industry is banking/financing, or consulting, or a primarily customer facing role, usually you will have to suit up.

As for the rest of the software industry in Europe, usually the stance is pretty casual when it comes for how you dress for it.

As again, ask your interviewers, and if they say casual, a safe bet would be high-street, expensive clothes for that trial interview and your first days at the job.

As for suits in continental Europe, we tend more for darker colours especially in the winter time (black, grey, brown, blue - I personally do not favour much blue). In Southern European countries, lighter colours in the summer time are *usually* acceptable.

Beware of (very) cheap suits, they may not look like good on you. I also prefer an European/Italian cut to an American cut.

As a last piece of advice, even if is a casual wear environment at the job, I would invest on at least a good suit. It might come handy for a formal party or a meeting with an important customer.

P.S. When in the UK, due to the cultural connotations with a work uniform, going to a party with a black suit and white tie is not particularly seen as smart dressing.

Comment: @Richard There are people buying €5000 Armani suits...as a ballpark, usually my suits are between 500-700 except when in the sales season, when you can find a 500 one for around 300.

Comment: @Richard At the end of the day, it is up to you and your potcket. I personally do not find 100-200 euros and american cuts suits me well. Beware of the euro-pound conversions. I usually plan buying them in sales for around half price.

Comment: I wouldn't think spending that much on a suit is necessary, especially for a software engineer job where dress codes are generally more relaxed. I doubt if any interviewer would notice, let alone care. There are far more important things to worry about.

Comment: For sales looking sharp is important - your customer is judging you and it will impact your performance. For working in an office - you are just showing people you care enough to have tried. Nobody is going to turn down an software engineer based on their suit being ill-fitting or cheap (you could get one at H&M and you'd be fine).

Comment: I prefer neither using cheap suits, nor american cuts, it was an habit I got when I was a very well paid customer-facing consultant. Beware of the euro-pound rate :) I do however, coordinate my efforts for buying them at sales 2 or 3 for the price of 1. I think I would prefer to be seen around naked than wearing an H&M suit though.

Comment: @Richard   I edited out the price part at the end of the day as it is highly subjective.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Good I have always paid less than £100 for a suit and this includes flying to other countries to meet business partners. As a software engineer if a company cares more about my suit than my skills I do not want to work for them. Funnily enough one time I flew to Germany in a suit only to be met by a group of Germans in shorts laughing at me so its always best to ask ahead of time.

Comment: @kenjara That is also a cultural thing IMO. As you use black suits generally, you will find them for less. We tend to use slightly better suits, and it is also a age thing. Younger people use cheaper suits. I made once the faux pas of going to London, IBM technical training, 3 days with only suits in my luggage. Everyone with jeans and tshirts....

Answer (score 2):

What is involved in a trial day will differ from company to company. It may be an intense day at work where they include meetings, projects, and as many activities as they can in one day that would normaly be spread out over the course of many days. Many of the questions you have are fairly general, but I you need to consider why you're reluctant to ask the hiring company these questions.

Interviewing involves finding about the company as well. It would be a positive sign for you to ask questions so you can be prepared. If you're given a project or working with a client, asking questions is important. It helps you communicate with your boss to manage his or her expectations.

If they don't want to answer your questions or negatively judge you for asking, that would be a red flag. Good hosts make guests feel at ease. They let you know what to expect and anticipate problems. My guess is they've done this before, so they should know what they're doing.